# Передать в Sphinx текст, получить список слов в начальной форме

Tags: sphinx

Есть текст. Необходимо передать его в Sphinx, а обратно получить список слов в начальной форме (лемматизацией). В идеале список слов с количеством вхождения каждого (в начальное форме).

Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> список слов в начальной форме (лемматизацией).

Если имеется в виду получение лемм слов (а не наоборот), то через CALL KEYWORDS:

```
mysql> call keywords('школьников детей пароходы самолёту', 't', 1 as stats);
+------+----------------------+------------------+------+------+
| qpos | tokenized            | normalized       | docs | hits |
+------+----------------------+------------------+------+------+
| 1    | школьников           | школьник         | 1    | 1    |
| 2    | детей                | дет              | 0    | 0    |
| 3    | пароходы             | пароход          | 0    | 0    |
| 4    | самолету             | самолет          | 0    | 0    |
+------+----------------------+------------------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```